# The mighty man and the bridge

Tags: classical-mechanics

Let us say we have a mighty man crossing a bridge, carrying 4 bags of concrete, each of which weighs 50 pounds.

Let us say, for the sake of the argument, that the mighty man himself weighs 300 pounds.

The support capacity of the bridge $x$ is less than the 500 pounds they weigh together - therefore, the mighty man cannot carry the concrete in a stack across the bridge - it will fall.

However, the mighty man does have the ability to juggle all the concrete bags so that he is only in contact with one of them at a time.

Is there such a value of $x$ possible that he can cross the bridge juggling all four bags of concrete at once, or will the bridge necessarily exceed its support capacity?

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36167/16660

Comment: I recall this as a discussion in a physics class from several years ago... no idea what made think of it!